# Redirect `tr -d` on windows?

Tags: dos, tr, gnuwin32

I can't find a way to redirect the output of GnuWin32's `tr` to a file:

```
(dev) go|w:\srv> dkversion . | jq .vcs | tr -d \" > vcs.txt
tr: extra operand `>'
Try `tr --help' for more information.
Error: writing output failed: Invalid argument
```

The `dkversion . | jq .vcs` command outputs `"svn"`, so to reproduce it with a simpler testcase:

```
(dev) go|w:\srv> echo "svn"
"svn"

(dev) go|w:\srv> echo "svn" | tr -d \"
svn

(dev) go|w:\srv> echo "svn" | tr -d \" > vcs.txt
tr: extra operand `>'
Try `tr --help' for more information.
```

on linux `echo '"svn"' | tr -d '"' > foo.txt` works, so I'm guessing the problem has to do with the quoting of the `"`..?  I haven't been able to figure out what the correct syntax would be though..

Comment: You might want to try redirection before options: `tr >vcs.txt -d \"`

Comment: @CiaPan that works!   Make it into an answer and I'll give you points :-)

Comment: I don't care much about points :) although it's nice to get them. Anyway I make an answer just to complete the 'Q&A' routine.

Comment: Alas the trick works for redirecting to a file only. It will not work if you need to pipe results to another command – if you put options after the piping metasymbol, they become the other command's options. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put redirection before options:

```
tr > vcs.txt -d \"
```